# Is using JSON field inside table, to speed up some relationship database queries - a good idea?

Tags: c#, sql, json, serialization

I have read some topics but, I'm still not sure is it good or bad so...

Current project I work on have some tables with self relation. They are used to create - in theory - endless pyramid like hierarchy, with root on top, and every other object referencing its parent. Problem is - we have at least few methods that require pretty deep iteration in order to get desired data, for example: we have some warehouse item that is connected to the parent item (it is a part of the item), which is connected to the sub-warehouse which is connected to the primary warehouse - if user selects that warehouse item, we want to display the primary warehouse it’s connected to.

I wonder if JSON could help us speed up lockup of primary warehouse in the above situation? I know we could create simple class, serialize it and then use it for our needs, but I don’t know if it is a good or bad idea?

I can see potential benefits, but also potential threats - if someone, for example: updates database by hand and relation changes, JSON will be outdated although I can see a potential workaround - I could compare UpdatedAt in JSON and in database and if they are different - regenerate JSON before query.

What is your experience with such mixes?

Comment: it not the ideal for a typical RDBMS but if you really wanted there are tools for that for example http://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: @meda:

I'm afraid NoSql DB's are no good for us - 99% of data is tabular data, perfectly suited for RDB (not to mention that EF doesn't support any NiSQL DBs right now), there are some "corner cases" here and there and I would like to speed them up if possible, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: PostgreSQL may be more suitable here, it has very good Json support, and it works with EF, have a look at https://functionwhatwhat.com/json-in-postgresql/

Comment: @user3473830:

Hmm interesting - I see MySql also have some support for JSON, unfortunately we are stuck with MS SQL (shame on Microsoft, they don't have any support for JSON yet :( ) - no way around it. Thanks for the info anyway - it will be useful in our future projects.

Answer (score 3):

It's ok to store denormalized values/structured strings in your sql database, but the problem with JSON is that you have very limited query capabilities in regards to values in the json.
However, you have to decide if that is a limiting factor for you.

SQL Server actually has better support for xml, but if you are storing complex json documents, it might be worthwhile to consider a nosql option that is more suitable for json structures (MongoDb etc).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - I realize we can't use that JSON in our queries - but, I think it would still be a lot faster to simply get that JSON for our row, deserialize it, and take "RootWarehouseId" from it, then to iterate over 3-5 other rows in a while() loop just to get RootWarehouseId - even more so since we have some code that actually loads a lot of data that way. I just don't know if there are some "quirks" I'm not aware of at the moment, that will make hell out of this later on ;]